# Convert JSON to HashMap using XStream

Tags: java, json, hashmap, converters, xstream

I have a JSON String of the map form :

{
  "Lucy":{
    "id": 456,
    "full_name": "GOOBER, ANGELA",
    "user_id": "2733245678",
    "stin": "2733212346"
  },
  "Myra":{
    "id": 123,
    "full_name": "BOB, STEVE",
    "user_id": "abc213",
    "stin": "9040923411"
  }
}

I want to convert it to HashMap with keys as "Lucy", "Myra" etc. and values as JavaObject

```
Class Person
{
String id;
String fullName;
String userId;
Strring stin;

}
```

How would I do it ? I kind of have a hint that I need to use MapConverter, but there is little documentation on how to. I have created Lists (using addImplicitCollection) using XStream but have no idea about Map.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with "jackson" too

```
ObjectMapper objMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Person> mpCards =  objMapper.readValue(strJSONString, new TypeReference<Map<String, Person>>(){});
```

Comment: Thanks I ended up using Jackson because could not figure out how to use XStream for this. I was wondering if you know how to ignore a node while parsing using Jackson

Comment: Ignore node means, you want to skip some properties in your Person class? Can you let me know in detail please?

Answer (score 0):

Translate the JSON into a map of maps.  Iterate through the outer map, obtain the value (inner map of) of the map entry, and pass it to a constructor for your object that accepts a map and constructs the corresponding object.  Replace the pointer to the inner map with a pointer to the constructed object.  (To make Java generics happy you might need to create a new map vs updating values in the old.)

Pseudo-code (can be pretty much anywhere):

```
Map<String, Map> theWholeThing = myJSONParser.parseJSONIntoObject(theWholeJSONString);
Map<String, Person> theNewThing = new HashMap<String, Person>();
// Use your favorite Map iterating style -- I picked this at random
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : theWholeThing.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    Map<String, String> value = entry.getValue();
    Person person = new Person(value);
    theNewThing.put(key, person);
}
return theNewThing;
```

In class Person:

```
Person(Map<String, String) map) {
    this.id = map.get("id");
    this.fullName = map.get("full_name");
    this.userId = map.get("user_id");
    this.stin = map.get("stin");
}
```

If you prefer you can create a `FromJsonMap` static factory method on `Person`, rather than making it a constructor.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more with example code. I cannot modify the JSON structure ( have no control over it! ) .